# How to have working breadcrumbs with several taxonomies associated with a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a breadcrumb / navigation problem. I don't know if it's possible to achieve what i want or if i can do it with mysetings or not.

I have a custom post type "Formation", for which i created 2 custom taxonomies :
"Formation type" (formationtype) => hierachical
"Formation public" (formationpublic) => non hierarchical

Formation type :

- FT1

  - FT1.1
  - FT1.
- FT2

  - FT2.1

And "formation public"
public1, public2, ...

I want to have this menu links :

...

- Formations    (non clickable)

  - FT 1     (clickable)
  - FT 2     (clickable)

and when I click on FT 1, I have a page displaying a list of all formation of type FT1

- FT11

  - formation1 of type FT11
  - formation2 of type FT11
- FT2

  - formation1 of type FT12
  - formation2 of type FT12

And finally when i click on one of the formations : "formation1 of type FT11" i get the complete description of that formation.

So my goal is to be able to make a breabcrumb like :

`<Home> / <Formation> / FT1`

with the url :  http://mydomain/formation/formation1-of-type-FT11
And

`<Home> / <Formation> / <FT1> / <FT11> / formation1 of type FT11`

**With all the non final elements <...> being clickable to be able to navigate through the breadcrumb and not having to go back to the menu.**

Since I create my lists with custom requests, if i use any breadcrumb tool, i only get  something like :
Home / FT1 (at best)

For the second type of taxonomy, I associate one or several terms from "formationpublic" (doctor, nurse, ...) to a formation, I have in the complete description of that formation :

- formation1 of type FT11
- Public : ,
- Description ....

If i choose doctor, i have the list of all formation for doctors, but i choose from there a formation i loose the breadcrumb, it is different from the Formation type path.
I have the url : http://mydomain/formation/formation1-of-type-FT11

So my question is what would you suggest as a structure to have "working" breadcrumbs as i (tried to) explain ?
Thank you

Comment: breadcrumbs are UI element that have nothing to do with your DB structure. Use a more flexible tool or write your own breadcrumb code

Comment: I wasn't clear enough : it's not about the db structure i'm asking advice for, it's about the way the post/pages should be handled : can i achieve this (having a clear breadcrumb) with custom post type and taxonomy ou should i use maybe only pages, which i think natively are well handled with any breadcrumb tool, but on the downside is "ugly" as i don't use CPT which are made for this. I can't wrap my head around this problem.

Comment: CPT, posts, pages, taxonomies are DB structures that have nothing to do with how your UI looks. Write your own breadcrumbs code and you will be able to do anything.

Comment: It will end to that eventually, but i was wondering if there was a way, as is, to achieve my goal, without rewriting a one-purpose breadcrumb.

Comment: The general problem with breadcrumbs is that they are artifact of the past which do not map well into the way modern websites are built. Modern websites are just not built like a document tree therefor the is not much point in trying to present a tree like path. You can get to a post from the home page, category, tag or author page so why should only one of those options be presented in the breadcrumb. sorry for this small rant, just needed to get it out of my system ;)

Comment: I understand your point, up to a point : unless you use WP like a dropzone for post, without classification, if you use categories, tags or generally taxonomies in your posts, you create "trees". The problem is how wp treats differently trees from taxonomies than trees from parenthood between pages for instance. I haven't dig enough maybe in WP functions, but i haven't found (nor in any forum) a Grail for this kind of problem. So that said, i still have no clue how to proceed.